# Finding Fields with dynamic ID's using Selenium WebDriver c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium-webdriver

I have the following example, where fields will either be displayed or not depending on what report you select.

In the Selenium code the Fields have been defined as:

```
 By Field1 = By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField1");
 By Field2 = By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField2");
 By Field3 = By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField3");
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>

<tr>
    <td>
        <span>Field1</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField1"   
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <span>Field2</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField2"   
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        <span>Field3</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id="ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField3"   
            <option value="1">Yes</option>
            <option value="0">No</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

If I select (Report 1)

```
1) Then all Fields are displayed
2) Field 1: (id="ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField1")
3) Field 2: (id="ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField2")
4) Field 3: (id="ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField3")
```

If I select (Report 3)

```
1) Then Field 2 is removed (id="ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField2")
2) As only 2 Fields are now displayed on the screen the ID's are now as follows
3) Field 1: (id="ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField1")
4) Field 3: (id="ctl00_MainContent_cntrlDynamicField2")
```

The automation will always fail because I want to use Field 3 but the ID has changed.

The selenium scripts are data driven from a xls sheet.

How do i continue to find Field3 even through the ID has changed dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame your `<td><span>Field3</span></td>` is not a label with a `for` attribute pointing to the right object. In that case you'd be able to identify based on text label.

There are two ways around this: Either use jQuery to find your element since selenium webdriver is an `IJavascriptExecutor`... you could find spans with your text specifically and use:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp

The other option is use `By.CssSelector` and not `By.Id` and depending on browser you might be able to use an adjacent CSS selector:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

Answer (score 0):

The code below grabs each table row and looks for the text, "Field3". Once that text is found, it retrieves the `SELECT` from that row and stores it in the variable, `select`.

```
String searchText = "Field3";
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (WebElement row : rows)
{
    if (row.getText().contains(searchText))
    {
        Select select = new Select(row.findElement(By.tagName("select")));
        break;
    }
}
```